# Recent Android SDK update causing application to crash

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mobile

I recently updated to the most recent version of the Android SDK. Before the update my application was working perfectly fine. Now Im getting the following error at the beginning of runtime. I try to debug at the beginning of my first Activity, but my application doesn't seem to get that far. Does anyone know what I need to do to get my application back up and running?

```
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.my_application.my_application:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my_application.my_application
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:490)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3779)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1082)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my_application.my_application
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:966)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:951)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:481)
08-29 13:45:27.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5266):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I am not sure about this but can you have your package name and sub-package name same ?

Comment: I made an error inside my manifest. Good eye swayam!

Comment: if swayam helped you out, you should mark his answer as accepted.  Both to reward him and to help out future users who might encounter a similar problem and come here from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
com.my_application.my_application
```

Looks like the problem was the **same name** for both the **package** and the **sub-package**.

So, a *minor edit in your manifest* should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago my teammate have nearly the same problem, but runtime exception occures just after calling to another activity(on emulator). At the same time this project perfectly works on my machine and there were no problems due emulator debug runtime. The problem seems to be in  project dependency libraries mismatch (project prop-java build path-libraries). For some reason ***"Android dependecies"*** classpath was excluded from this list, no errors where due compilation time.

Try

```
Android Tools->Fix project properties
```

It helped in our case